# IntelliJ: How do I move the position of the method parameter popup hint?

Tags: intellij-idea

When I'm working in IntelliJ, I often get this popup window that helps to see what method signatures I can use. 
[image: method help popup]

It's helpful sometimes, so I don't want to disable it, but in certain situations like this, it blocks my view and I don't know what I'm doing. Is there a way to move the position of this pop-up to under the code being typed instead of above? Basically, I'd still like the pop-up, but I'd like to see the code above it.

Comment: You can [disable this popup](https://i.imgur.com/WHsdVvD.png) and invoke it manually when needed using Ctrl/Cmd+P.  See also https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-106333 and the related tickets.